# Unity UI Button keeps double clicking, how can I work around this?

Tags: unity-game-engine, uibutton

I have two buttons set up in an interactive fiction game, each press calls a new line of text. The problem is, every time I press on the button, I get two logged debug messages informing me of the click and my game moves two sections of text.

I've tried many different things to try to work around this including trying to alter the submit input in project settings and many different code forms. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my current code:

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class AdventureGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Text _textComponent;
    [SerializeField]
    private State _startingState;

    private State state;

    [SerializeField]
    private Button _input0Button;
    [SerializeField]
    private Button _input1Button;

    [SerializeField]
    private Text _choices1;
    [SerializeField]
    private Text _choices2;

    private bool _buttonOnePressed;
    private bool _buttonTwoPressed;

    void Start()
    {
        state = _startingState;
        _textComponent.text = state.GetStateStory();
        _input0Button.onClick.AddListener(Input0Button);
        _input1Button.onClick.AddListener(Input1Button);
        _buttonOnePressed = false;
        _buttonTwoPressed = false;


    }
    void Update()
    {
        ManageState();
    }
    private void ManageState()
    {
        if (state._choice == true)
        {
            _choices1.text = state.GetChoiceOne();
            _choices2.text = state.GetChoiceTwo();
            _textComponent.text = state.GetStateStory();
            _input0Button.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            _input1Button.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            if(_buttonOnePressed == true)
            {
                StartCoroutine(WaitForItOne());
            }
            else if(_buttonTwoPressed == true)
            {
                StartCoroutine(WaitForItTwo());
            }
        }
        else if (state._choice == false)
        {
            _choices1.text = state.GetChoiceOne();
            _choices2.text = state.GetChoiceTwo();
            _textComponent.text = state.GetStateStory();
            _input0Button.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            _input1Button.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            if(_buttonOnePressed == true)
            {
                StartCoroutine(WaitForItOne());
            }
        }

    }
    private void ManageChoiceOne()
    {
            _buttonOnePressed = false;
            State[] _newState = state.GetNextStatesArray();
            state = _newState[0];
    }
    private void ManageChoiceTwo()
    {
            _buttonTwoPressed = false;
            State[] _newState = state.GetNextStatesArray();
            state = _newState[1];
    }

    public void Input0Button()
    {
        Debug.Log("Input 0 pressed");
        _buttonOnePressed = true;
    }
    public void Input1Button()
    {
        Debug.Log("Input 1 pressed");
        _buttonTwoPressed = true;
    }
    IEnumerator WaitForItOne()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.0f);
        ManageChoiceOne();
    }
    IEnumerator WaitForItTwo()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.0f);
        ManageChoiceTwo();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

- First of all you keep starting new Coroutines each frame as long as e.g. `_buttonOnePressed == true` .. you wait 3 seconds before you finally unset this flag!
- Then for the double call make sure the callbacks are not configured also in the Inspector! It seems like you have them once in the Inspector and additionally add them in your `Start` method so they are called **twice**!

  Note that you won't see the callbacks added on runtime in the Inspector!
- Why are you even using `Update` here at all? It is quite redundant to poll the state and the bool values and constantly check and handle their states in each frame. I would rather simply start the routine in the button method itself and make the whole code event driven instead!
- (optionally) To give the user better feedback I would additionally in the meantime during the 3 seconds make the buttons non-interactable .. keep them active but not clickable:

```c#
// Remove state;
// Remove _buttonOnePressed
// Remove _buttonTwoPressed

private void Start()
{
    // Either remove this two lines or the callbacks set in the Inspector
    _input0Button.onClick.AddListener(Input0Button);
    _input1Button.onClick.AddListener(Input1Button);

    ManageState(_startingState);
}

// Remove Update

// This will be called only when actually needed
// since the state is passed in as parameter you don't need the private field
private void ManageState(State state)
{
    // These happen in both cases anyway
    _choices1.text = state.GetChoiceOne();
    _choices2.text = state.GetChoiceTwo();
    _textComponent.text = state.GetStateStory();
    _input0Button.gameObject.SetActive(true);

    // Here directly use the state flag
    // since the button is disabled when needed
    // there is no need for having different "states"
    // since anyway only the according button(s) is(are) available
    _input1Button.gameObject.SetActive(state._choice);
}

// (optional) Flag for avoiding concurrent routines
// Should be impossible since buttons get disabled but you never know
private bool alreadyHandlingButton;

private IEnumerator ManageChoice(bool isButtonOne)
{
    // (optional) Skip if another routine running
    if(alreadyHandlingButton) yield break;

    // (optional) Block other routines just in cade
    alreadyHandlingButton = true;

    // Disable interactions
    _input0Button.interactable = false;
    _input1Button.interactable = false;

    // This is the same for both buttons
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

    State[] _newState = state.GetNextStatesArray();
     
    var state = _newState[isButtonOne ? 0 : 1];

    // Only call ManageState when the state is actually changing
    ManageState(state);

    // (optional) Allow a new routine
    alreadyHandlingButton = false;

    // Enable interactions
    _input0Button.interactable = true;
    _input1Button.interactable = true;
}

public void Input0Button()
{
    // (optional) Ignore if other button is already handled
    if(alreadyHandlingButton) return;

    Debug.Log("Input 0 pressed");
    StartCoroutine(ManageChoice(true));
}

public void Input1Button()
{
    // (optional) Ignore if other button is already handled
    if(alreadyHandlingButton) return;

    Debug.Log("Input 1 pressed");
    StartCoroutine(ManageChoice(false));
}
```